# How do you automatically recycle tapes in Retrospect 7.6 for Windows?

Tags: backup

What is the best way to setup Retrospect to recycle tapes automatically? I would have thought this to be very straight forward but everything I have come across so far seems to indicate otherwise.

Example: I have a backup set named Daily Users that consists of two member tapes. What I want Retrospect to do is Automatically reuse tape 1 when tape 2 gets full. What is the best way to do this without having to go in and manually recycle the tape?

Also, if you could share what your retrospect backup settings are that would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually setup automatic grooming via the Retrospect Policy.

Or you can setup another backup script or backup run time that does a recycle backup automatically.

But you are better off using the automatic grooming or even scheduled grooming
[Backup Overview for Retrospect 7.5](http://www.retrospect.com/assets/wp_d2d2t_en.pdf) (It still applies mostly to 7.6/7.7

Comment: Thank you for the script suggestion tegbains. I have looked at that pdf before and my understanding from it though is that grooming can only be applied on a disk to disk scenario, not disk to tape due to the linear nature of tape. Am I mistaken?

Comment: I figured it out. The secret was to assign multiple sets to the same script. Then you can create multiple schedules like the ones you mentioned e.g. normal and recycle to reuse the tapes. Also, for the record, grooming does only apply to disk to disk scenarios and not to tape backups.